# Issue with maven compile

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, testng, pom.xml

When trying to build in jenkins an E2E project using selenium wd and testng , I got the following error:

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /Users/VickoS/.jenkins/E2EProject/src/main/java/resources/ExtentReporterNG.java:[9,18] package org.testng does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/VickoS/.jenkins/E2EProject/src/main/java/resources/ExtentReporterNG.java:[10,18] package org.testng does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/VickoS/.jenkins/E2EProject/src/main/java/resources/ExtentReporterNG.java:[11,18] package org.testng does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/VickoS/.jenkins/E2EProject/src/main/java/resources/ExtentReporterNG.java:[12,18] package org.testng does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/VickoS/.jenkins/E2EProject/src/main/java/resources/ExtentReporterNG.java:[13,18] package org.testng does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/VickoS/.jenkins/E2EProject/src/main/java/resources/ExtentReporterNG.java:[14,18] package org.testng does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/VickoS/.jenkins/E2EProject/src/main/java/resources/ExtentReporterNG.java:[15,22] package org.testng.xml does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/VickoS/.jenkins/E2EProject/src/main/java/resources/ExtentReporterNG.java:[21,42] cannot find symbol
  symbol: class IReporter
[ERROR] /Users/VickoS/.jenkins/E2EProject/src/main/java/resources/ExtentReporterNG.java:[24,37] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class XmlSuite
  location: class resources.ExtentReporterNG
[ERROR] /Users/VickoS/.jenkins/E2EProject/src/main/java/resources/ExtentReporterNG.java:[24,63] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ISuite
  location: class resources.ExtentReporterNG
[ERROR] /Users/VickoS/.jenkins/E2EProject/src/main/java/resources/ExtentReporterNG.java:[43,33] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class IResultMap
  location: class resources.ExtentReporterNG
[INFO] 11 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  4.605 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-04-03T19:51:37-03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project E2EProject: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /Users/VickoS/.jenkins/E2EProject/src/main/java/resources/ExtentReporterNG.java:[9,18] package org.testng does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/VickoS/.jenkins/E2EProject/src/main/java/resources/ExtentReporterNG.java:[10,18] package org.testng does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/VickoS/.jenkins/E2EProject/src/main/java/resources/ExtentReporterNG.java:[11,18] package org.testng does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/VickoS/.jenkins/E2EProject/src/main/java/resources/ExtentReporterNG.java:[12,18] package org.testng does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/VickoS/.jenkins/E2EProject/src/main/java/resources/ExtentReporterNG.java:[13,18] package org.testng does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/VickoS/.jenkins/E2EProject/src/main/java/resources/ExtentReporterNG.java:[14,18] package org.testng does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/VickoS/.jenkins/E2EProject/src/main/java/resources/ExtentReporterNG.java:[15,22] package org.testng.xml does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/VickoS/.jenkins/E2EProject/src/main/java/resources/ExtentReporterNG.java:[21,42] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol: class IReporter
[ERROR] /Users/VickoS/.jenkins/E2EProject/src/main/java/resources/ExtentReporterNG.java:[24,37] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class XmlSuite
[ERROR]   location: class resources.ExtentReporterNG
[ERROR] /Users/VickoS/.jenkins/E2EProject/src/main/java/resources/ExtentReporterNG.java:[24,63] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ISuite
[ERROR]   location: class resources.ExtentReporterNG
[ERROR] /Users/VickoS/.jenkins/E2EProject/src/main/java/resources/ExtentReporterNG.java:[43,33] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class IResultMap
[ERROR]   location: class resources.ExtentReporterNG
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

This was not happening when running the mvn compile command before, but after updating my POM and re-compiling, it started to show in the terminal too. The project works perfectly fine when running it from the testng.xml in eclipse.

Here's how my POM file looks like

```
 <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>



  <build>
   <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering> 
        </resource>
    </resources>
  <plugins>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
        <configuration>
          <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
          </suiteXmlFiles>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
          <configuration>
             <source>1.8</source>
             <target>1.8</target>
          </configuration>
       </plugin>
</plugins>


  </build>
  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.apple</groupId>
      <artifactId>AppleJavaExtensions</artifactId>
      <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

       <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>  

    <dependency>
  <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
  <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
  <version>7.1.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.6</version>
</dependency>

 <dependency>
<groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
<artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
<version>2.41.2</version>
</dependency>

      <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.2</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.2</version>
  </dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Attaching image of how the project looks like:

[Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gf6K5.png)

Comment: remove <scope>test</scope> from testng dependency in pom file. Save the pom file and then compile, It should work.

Comment: Remove the configuration `src/main/java/resources` cause it violates the convention over configuration paradigm. Furthermore you should locate resources by default in `src/main/resources` instead...and cleanup the compile error first ..

Comment: if you want to use testng to do something the classes that can see that dependency need to go into src/test/java - so move ExtentReporterNG.java into that folder structure - the path /src/main/java/resources/ looks very weird. Is "resources" your package name? Or was something moved around by accident?

Comment: removing "test" from scope doesn't work.
And yes, resources is the package name

Comment: @Vicko If `resources` is  package name (might be bad idea) but than you should not add resource filtering on that cause within a package only `*.java` should be located ...resources (property files etc.) should be located in `src/main/resources` ...

Comment: @khmarbaise you mean there might be confusion in the resources package? removing the filters do not work. I attached an image of how the project looks like.

I don't get why this was initially not failing and now it does. Also the project works if I run from testng.xml directly

Comment: That's exactly what I feared. The property file and the `log4j.xml` belong into `src/main/resources` if it's intended to pack them into the resulting jar. Furthermore package names should always be lowercase only.

Comment: Cannot find symbol means that you're using the classes but they can't be found. Go to the classes that use IReporter .... and check the imports. And please open your Jenkins workspace and check if the resources folder has the jar. But I suggest to remove the jars from resources and do import to maven dependencies, looks like there is a conflict between the jars of the dependencies and the imported jars in resources.

Comment: @NaelMarwan I checked the project in the Jenkins workspace and everything's in there. I deleted and added the project again and mvn -compile works for the project in eclipse now but not for the jenkins project. I'm very confused now

Comment: Make sure that Jenkins has the same Maven version on your machine. It could be Incompatibility issue.

Comment: Updating here that the build passed after removing anything related to the ExtentReports. That still doesn't solve why It worked perfectly from eclipse and not from jenkins

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to solve this by updating my POM file doing the following:
Removing the extent report dependency that had the avenstack groupID

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.6</version>
</dependency>
```

updating the other Extent Report to this v:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
     <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
     <version>3.1.5</version>
  </dependency>
```

And adding this one too:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
        <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.28</version>
    </dependency>
```